# Dealing with time in different timezones react/javascript (PST/PDT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime, date-fns

So I have this use case where a user should be able to enter data into a react site having an `order_fulfilment_datetime_str` which is supposed to be a `RFC 3339` datetime string according to the specs of the api this would be posted to.

So essentially a user(in any timezone) selects a (future) date and time (using a plugin such as react-datepicker) assuming that the date time is going to be in PST/PDT.
But the plugin and javascript date object returns the selected date time in the browser's timezone. So I have two things to solve:

1. How do I make sure that selected date/time is in PST/PDT
2. How to deal with DST?

Currently what I am trying to do is to simply get individual date, hours, minutes using `getHours()`, `getMinutes()`, `getDate()` to form the string. But again then how will I find out if this selected datetime has offset of -8 or -7(i.e. PST/PDT)?

I checked `date-fns` and `date-fns-tz` library but was not sure how to solve this issue using these.

Comment: Hi, Have you looked at luxon library?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari not yet. But checking. Not sure yet how will that solve my problem. If you know how that can solve my problem, pls put your answer.

Comment: "*… javascript date object returns the selected date time in the browser's timezone*" It can't do that, Date objects do not have any idea of timezones, they're just an offset from the ECMAScript epoch. The string displayed by *toString* uses system settings to generate a timestamp for the host clock and regional timezone settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use luxon library for setting a global timezone that you want, and then whenever a user selects a date-time using a date-time picker you can simply convert that into the timezone you want.

```
import { Settings } from "luxon"
Settings.defaultZone = <time-zone>
```

The above code snippet will set a default zone for the app

Now when a user selects a date-time convert it to the timezone you want using the below code

```
DateTime.fromISO(dateTimeValue, { setZone: true})
```